# Android: regex for edit text to have only 2 values possible in decimal

Tags: android, regex

In my filter used into EditText, I want to be sure the user can only set .5 or .0 for decimal values.

Valid values examples:

- 34.5
- 34.0
- 34

Invalid values examples:

- 34.2
- 34.8
- 34.6

I tried this one, but it doesn't work properly: `[0-9]*[.]?[0|5]`

Thank you very much guys!

Comment: You could try `^[0-9]+\.(?:5|2)$` regex, here is demo: https://regex101.com/r/p8mEQQ/1 for same. OR in case you need to match only 2 digits from starting then try: `^[0-9]{2}\.(?:5|2)$`.

Comment: I modified regex by @RavinderSingh13 a bit, so it accepts numbers without decimal places as well:
`^[0-9]+(\.(?:5|0))?$`

Comment: I think you are looking for `^[0-9]+(?:[.][05])?$` https://regex101.com/r/z4h9MC/1

Answer (score 1):

You're probably looking for `[0-9]*(\.([50][0]*)*)*`.

`[0-9]*`: Any character from 0 to 9, zero or more times [so that just a "." (= 0.0) input is valid]

`\.`: You need to escape the '.' character, since it usually would mean "any character", and you especifically need the dot there.

`[50][0]*`: First, either five or zero (once). Second, the 0 character, zero or more times (since 35.50 = 35.5). This also avoids inputs like 35.59 from being valid, since 9 != 0.

`([50][0]*)*`: This occurrence zero or more times, so that 35., for instance, becomes a valid input (since 35. = 35.0).

`(\.([50][0]*)*)*`: As for this grouping, it's in order to check for the five or the zero only if there is a decimal dot. It's grouping the dot character and the 5/0 logic together with a star (zero or more times) at the end, so if it doesn't occur, it still matches.

Let me know if this was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

To verify the whole numbers in the examples, you can make the last part optional and use anchors.

```
^[0-9]+(?:[.][05])?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[0-9]+` Match 1+ digits 0-9
- `(?:[.][05])?` Optionally match `.` and a digit 0 or 5
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/z4h9MC/1).

If you want to be able to only type a pattern like that and also accept empty strings or `34.` you can repeat the digit 0 or more times, optionally match `.` and optionally match either 0 or 5.

```
^[0-9]*[.]?[05]?$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KD1rjj/1)